# TypeError: Illegal invocation when calling getBoundingClientRect() on Proxy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

A simple code in JavaScript that shows the issue

```js
const obj = document.body;
const proxy = new Proxy(obj, {});
proxy.getBoundingClientRect();     // Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

How to access element's properties when object is proxified by third-party component (e.g. React's useRef which is then passed to ant design Table)?

```
const tableRef = useRef(undefined);
<Table ref={tableRef} />
```

Some more usage:

```
const onScroll = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // here throws Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    const tableRect = tableRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
};

const scroll = document.querySelector(`.ant-table-body`);
scroll?.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
```

Comment: React's `useRef` does not proxify anything.

Comment: @Bergi: might be proxied by ant design Table component

Comment: Then that would be a bug in the component. Can you show the actual code that you're having trouble with, please? In general, if you are handed a (broken) proxy by someone else, there's nothing you can do about it.